# Collapse Inline Visualforce section on standard page layout

Tags: visualforce, javascript, inline-visualforce

By default I want my inline visual force section to be collapsed.I can only see show scrollbar,Height,Width and Show label under pagelayout settings.I know salesforce remembers the collapsed state.But In my case I always want my inline visual force section to be collapsed.How to achieve this.

**Update**

I have created a hidden visualforce page(Zero height/Width) with Javascript code for collapsing my inline visualforce section on pageload and added it to page layout, but its not working.Can some one help me where I am going wrong.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<script language="javascript">
 function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

function dotest() {

 if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.head_01B3000000CARvA_ep}') != null){
     twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.head_01B3000000CARvA_ep}').childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);
 }
}
addLoadEvent(dotest);
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: are you willing to do a VF page that consists solely of an apex:detail tag and override the View button to point at the VF page? If so, then jQuery/javascript can be used on that page to do the auto-collapsing

Comment: No.I don't want to override the view button with vf page.

Comment: @crop1645 can we do a hidden visualforce page(zero height/width) on standard page layout with javascript in it.

Comment: pass - out of my area of expertise

Comment: $Component will refer to the 'hidden VF page' id hierarchy which will not be the standard page layout id hierarchy

Comment: @crop1645 $Component.head_01B3000000CARvA_ep  is the ID of my inline vf section

Comment: @sf.dev show show love and bump the bounty.People may give it a shot for extra 50 reps. I tried to do this, but felt that there is too much traversing through the DOM to get the Id to pass to the twistsection().

Comment: @rao I can't do it now I have wait for more than 20 hrs for bounty

Answer (score 2):

This knowledge article gives an Idea on how to collapse the Pageblocksection by default.If you have the inline components in a separate pageblock section you can do the following to collapse it by default.

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181821&language=en_US

Comment: I want it on inline visualforce page on standard pagelayout not on a visualforce page with pageblocksections in it.

Comment: Duh my bad, the only way to modify standard page behavior is a sidebar hack. Earlier we could embed javascript in the section header,salesforce does not allow it anymore. Will be interesting to know if there is any one else who has a better trick to achieve this.

Comment: Can you show me how to achieve this using side bar component.